# DOMPDF is not rendering view with Bootrap in laravel properly

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, dompdf

i want to save a laravel view as PDF file and attach it to an email and it actually works but the view including bootstrap styling is not rendered properly as shown in the screenshot below. Bootstrap seems to be loading but not working as it should. Any suggestions how to fix this?

view: offer.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Col A
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Col B
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Col C
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Col A
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Col B
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Col C
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller: PDFController

```
class PDFController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {




        $data["email"] = "test@gmail.com";
        $data["name"] = "This is the Name";

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.offer', $data)->setpaper('A4', 'landscape');



        Mail::send('emails.offermail', $data, function($message)use($data, $pdf) {
            $message->to($data["email"], $data["name"])
                ->subject($data["title"])
                ->attachData($pdf->output(), "text.pdf");
        });


        return 'Email sent';
    }
}
```

[image: result PDF file]

Answer (score 0):

DOMPdf does not support bootstrap-4. You can try bootstrap-3. But I would recommend using css only in dompdf.